# DFT Polyphase Filter bank

Tags: filter-design, dft, filter-bank

What is the purpose of DFT & IDFT blocks which are placed after the Analysis filter bank & before the Synthesis filter bank.
The reason i am asking this question is because I tried to design Polyphase DFT filter bank & got the same output with & without DFT-IDFT block.

Comment: what is the major difference between th dft and polyphase dft with contrast of improving resolution and
what is the size of dft for n point polyphase 2,4 and 8.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are referring to an implementation like the one shown [here](http://cnx.org/content/m10424/latest/). If you leave out the DFT/IDFT blocks, then you don't have the modulation step which is necessary for actually implementing a filter bank, and you will not be able to do appropriate sub-band processing between the analysis and synthesis stages.

When you test your analysis and synthesis stages without sub-band processing in between you will obviously get the same result if you leave out the DFT/IDFT blocks. Analysis and synthesis together are then a pure delay and you might as well replace everything by a pure delay, but this defeats the purpose of the filter bank which is to split the input signal into sub-bands for further processing, and then to reconstruct the original signal from these separate sub-bands.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Cleared some of my concepts. Also, when u say sub-band processing(separating i/p into different freq. bands) does the DFT block does sub-band processing or does it just facilitates it. I mean to say, does the output of DFT block give me M sub-band signals in frequency OR do i have to add some more blocks after DFT to break the signal into M freq sub bands?

Comment: Each DFT bin corresponds to 1 sub-band, so with an $M$-point DFT you have $M$ sub-bands.

Comment: I have 4 signals in the freq band from -35MHz to 35Mhz. Using direct form I am able to split the signals into 4 sub-bands at 4 outputs of analysis filter. But when i try to implement this in Polyphase form, i am not able to split them. I am using 4 pt DFT matrix as given in the Wikipedia article. Is there a mistake i am making?

Comment: ykt is a 4x65567 matrix is the output of Analysis bank. W is a 4x4 DFT matrix. My output yktDFT=W X ykt . Is this the correct way to generate output?

Comment: You should add some more information to your original question, and formulate any other more detailed questions there. Try to be as clear as possible as to what you've done and how you've implemented everything. This will make it easier to help you.

Comment: i just joined this site & my reputation 1 is not allowing me to post images of my signals. Just help me with the following query - I am building 4 channel filter bank. My freq band is 0 - 70 MHZ. My lpf cutoff is 8.75MHz ie fs/8. When i build the analysis filters ie Ek(n)=h(nM+k) i get 4 filters, E0 E1 E2 E3. Since i am decimating in time, signal expands in frequency. So Each one of E0 E1 E2 & E3 become filters from 0 to fs/2 ie 0 to 35 MHz. Now, when i pass my input signal(also polyphased by 4) Do i need to add relative shifts of fs to each E1 E2 E3 filters or not?

Comment: I have one question in the derivation on the page you provided in your answer. Referring to Figure 2 on that page, if we are downconverting the signal to low pass filter it, we have to multiply with $e^{-j \dfrac{2 \pi kn}{M} }$ but it was given as $e^{j \dfrac{2 \pi kn}{M}}$. So, instead of doing DFT, I am ending up in doing IDFT. Can you tell me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: The page linked in the answer no longer exists.